# Form posted to paypal but callback doesn't contain custom fields

Tags: forms, callback, paypal, sandbox

I set up a sandbox account and I'm simulating payments with sandbox and logging $_POST array posted by paypal sandbox (simulating).

This is the form that I'm sending to paypal (not simulating)

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
   // charset, name, email, etc.
   // ...
   <input type='hidden' name='on0' value='Custom field 1 NAME'>
   <input type='hidden' name='os0' value='Custom field 1 VALUE'>
</form>
```

As you can see I have 1 custom field named on0.
How am I supposed to retrieve that value? I can't create custom fields on paypal's sandbox page.

Answer (score 0):

These should be variables that get returned back to you.  Can you provide the full PayPal button code that you are using.  Also, what is the method that you are using to return data back to your site?